# Symbolic link to a specific binary in /usr/local/bin doesn't seem to take effect

Tags: macos, symlink

I have both python 2 and python 3 installed on my Mac (Big Sur, 11.2.3, but I've had it for 6 years, so countless upgrades over time). Python 2 is what's being used by default, because the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python` is pointing to the python 2 install under `/System/library/...`.

I simply wanted to create the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/python` pointing to `/usr/bin/python3`. Note that I do not recall how the python3 binary made it to `/usr/bin`, but I don't seem to have a proper python 3 install on this system.

The gist of it is even if I run the symbolic link explicitly (fully qualified path), it is running python 2 instead of 3.

My path shows that `/usr/local/bin` has precedence over `/usr/bin`.

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/love.app/Contents/MacOS
```

I created the link like so:

```
% sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Verified it:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 userme  admin  16  9 May 11:36 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3
```

Verified that `/usr/bin/python3` is indeed python version 3:

```
% /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

But even referring to the link via fully qualified path name, I seem to be running the wrong binary:

```
% /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Seeing what resolves first in the path:

```
% which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Finally, I downloaded and installed a proper install of python 3. The symbolic link now points to it:

```
% ls -al /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69  9 May 11:52 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

Running the link explicitly now works:

```
% /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 3.9.5
```

But for some reason python 2 is still running when relying on resolution by path order:

```
% python --version
Python 2.7.16

% which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I'm a bit stumped. First, before having a proper install of python, how come I couldn't even resolve to `/usr/bin/python3` when invoking the symbolic link at `/usr/local/bin/python` with a fully qualified path? I don't have write permission to `/usr/bin/` due to SIP. But I don't see how this would prevent the link from functioning, given that running a binary only requires read/exec permissions.

(Note that I don't recall how I got python3 into there. It might have been prior to SIP, a really long time ago, or maybe I temporarily disabled it --but I doubt I would have done that just to stick a python3 binary in there).

With explicitly invoking the link now working with a python3 binary outside of `/usr/bin`, given that my path seems correct and the symbolic link is what it needs to be, any idea why invoking `python` still points to `/usr/bin/python3` ?

Edit: by starting a new terminal window (thus shell process I suppose), the path order seems to resolve as I would expect:

```
% python --version
Python 3.9.5
```

But I don't see how this should have helped in any way. Also, the original problem of explicitly invoking `/usr/local/bin/python` which pointed to `/usr/bin/python3` and still getting python 2 running is still stumping me. I can't explain either of those things.